# What is the "discussion" badge?

Tags: support, badges

I got this today:

[image]

But there is no reference to it in the 'Badges' page. Does this mean I talk too much? What did I win?

Comment: Someone with 11.6k rep on Meta is asking if he talks too much? ;)

Comment: (Yes, that comment is likely to come back and bite me later. Let me enjoy it while I can...)

Comment: @mmyers: not only "someone with 11.6k rep on MSO", more so "someone who just won a badge in the [discussion] tag on SO" :)

Comment: @mmyers - Shot at me, but I had to laugh none-the-less.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is a tag specific badge.  There are two tabs in the 'badges' page.  One for general badges, and one for tag specific badges.

[Tag Specific Badges](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges?tab=tags)

[Discussion Badge](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/42/discussion)

Comment: Ah, tag-specific badges. Thanks. Looking at the 'tabs' link to see how this works, I guess there's no way anyone's earning a `always-friday-in-iceland` badge, ever.